# Spyder crashed and deleted my py-file. How to recover file?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I finished my code and decided to clean it a little by renaming some variables. Basically renamed df2 to df4, for future purposes. I used the "Replace text" tool in spyder to replace them all instantly. When I pressed replace selection, the program crashed and I relaunched it and realized my saved .py file was completely deleted from my device. I need help recovering it!

My spyder version: 4.0.1 running on Python 3.7.6.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Google "file recovery utilities". I've used [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) with great success. The sooner you try to recover the file, the higher your chances are at 100% intact recovery.

Comment: Did you try enabling Deep Scan? It takes much longer (hours!), but may give you better results.  If it still doesn't work, the file is lost unless Spyder made a backup of it (backup options are usually set in Preferences somewhere).

Comment: I tried with Deep Scan and didn't find it. Also I couldn't find the backup settings in my spyder.

Comment: That is truly a tough situation. Your file has taken a one-way ticket to The Island of Lost Files :(